# SQL bulk insert into select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here's the situation

I have an SP in SQL which works on two `Table type variables` which are used to perform bulk insertion in to `Mails & attachments` respectively now they both have relationship in SQL of `one to many` of course on `MailId`, SP looks like this

```
MailInsertSP
  @Mails mailsTableVar
  @Attachements attachementsTableVar

-- this query will insert mails & generate MailIds
insert into Mails
( mails table column list... )
select
value list
from @Mails

-- this query will insert attachments
insert into Attachments
(MailId, other columns...)
select
(select MailId from Mails where MailDate = TBL.MailDate) as MailId,
other values
from @Attachements as TBL
```

Till now `MailDate` was `unique` for mails so this code was working fine but now I have got a situation where `MailDate` are same in two rows and I don't have any other column which could be used as unique key, So what I need is some solution so that I can insert in Mails and get generated Ids which can be used in next insertion of attachments.

It would be appreciable if solution would not have following

1. Any kind of loops.
2. Cursors.

Comment: Could you use a combination of MailDate and MailFrom (assuming you have that) to determine uniqueness instead of just MailDate?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the MailDate is unique in @Mails

```
insert into Attachments
(MailId, other columns...)
select
(select MailId from @Mails where MailDate = TBL.MailDate) as MailId,
other values
from @Attachements as TBL
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have one to many relationship between @mails and @attachments, for example column X. If so, you can user [merge...on 1=0....]/[output...] to merge @mail to your mail table and output mailID, and column X from @mail into temp table, then insert @attachment to table attachment, join with temp table which has maileid and X.

Comment: if there is no any unique relationship between your table variable mails and table variable attachments, then your issue is inevitable. For example, if you have fully duplicate record in @mails, then how can you distinguish which attachment belongs to which mail